# why Ajax return status 0 in IE11 but work well in other browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

We write AJAX in a CSHTML page. It works well in other browsers except IE10 and IE11. The problem is it returns `status=0` even though there is no error in the controller.

Is there someone met the problem before? How did you resolve it? We tried:

- add `cache: false`
- add `charset="UTF-8"`
- add `meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate"`

```js
ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "Create",
  data: { 'project': Parameters },
  dataType: "json",
  async: true,
  cache: false,
  complete: function (XHR, textStatus) {
    console.log('textStatus', textStatus);
    if (textStatus === 'error') {
      layer.alert("project sucess");
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have sharable link to the page where issue occurs so I could debug it?

Comment: now we found that if we remove some handling code in controller, even though these handling code didn't affect the return result. then the problem disappeared. but if we add such handling code, then it shows again